# Is Mailenable v5 compatible with Parallels Plesk 10?

Tags: email

I cannot find any official information on the Parallels web site to say whether the latest MailEnable Enterprise Edition (v5.0.7) is compatible with the latest Parallels Plesk Panel for Windows (v10.1.1). I can see some unofficial forum posts that suggest that only MailEnable v4.x can be used with Plesk 10. What are people's experiences? What will work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now managed to find the documentary evidence of the supported versions of the MailEnable system in Plesk v10.1.1. It can be found here:

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/release-notes/parallels-plesk-panel-10.1.1-for-windows-based-os.html

Ultimately, it seems that only v4.26 of MailEnable is supported in Plesk 10.1.1.

[EDIT: I contacted MailEnable. They told me that v5 is fully compatible, but that Plesk themselves would only be able to offer support for MailEnable v4.26 as that is what they are shipping. MailEnable themselves recommended using the latest v5.]